# Como chamar uma segunda chave em um dicionário usando o HDF5Matrix?

Tags: python, hdf5, keras

Eu estou tentando carregar um arquivo `.h5` usando esta documentação [`HDF5Matrix`](https://keras.io/utils/#HDF5Matrix):

```
test_images = HDF5Matrix(train_path+train_file,'images')
```

mas estou recebendo este erro:

> KeyError: "Unable to open object (object 'images' doesn't exist)"

Eu sei que é necessário usar esta sintaxe para chamar uma segunda chave em um dicionário `['train'] ['images']`.

Eu costumo usar essa instrução para abrir arquivos `.h5`:

```
with h5py.File(train_path+train_file, 'r') as hf:
      train_images = hf['train']['images'][:]
```

Minha pergunta é: É possível acessar a segunda chave para usar a sintaxe `HDF5Matrix`?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu finalmente consegui!

É muito fácil, os arquivos do tipo `h5` possuem essa estrutura:

```
file
  Group
    Dataset
```

Então, se quisermos acessar o `Dataset` usando `HDF5Matrix('path/file','dataset')`. Nós apenas temos que chamar o `Group` primeiro. Isso será assim:

```
from keras.utils import HDF5Matrix

x_data = HDF5Matrix('path/file', 'group/dataset')
```